# How to add to a bash script 2 enter button commands?

Tags: linux, bash

Evening everyone,

My question is im working on a bash script. Im having it ping a host and also banner grab using netcat. However ive no clue how to add the two enter buttons taps to the HEAD /HTTP/1.0 for it to banner grab the http port. Any suggestions are much welcome. Thank you Wez

Script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

for ip in $(cat ip-list.txt); 
do ping -c 1 $ip |grep "bytes from" |cut -d " " -f 4 |cut -d ":" -f 1 |sort -u &
done 

for ip in $ip 
do nc -nv $ip 80
done

for ip in $ip
do 
    HEAD /HTTP/1.0
done
```

Comment: two enter hit = `echo -ne "HEAD /HTTP/1.0\n\n"`

Comment: When i add this to my script it just behaves in the same way and waits. `(UNKNOWN) [192.168.10.15] 80 (http) open` what would you recommend? @jm666

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. I just used this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for ip in $(cat ip-list.txt); 
do ping -c 1 $ip |grep "bytes from" |cut -d " " -f 4 |cut -d ":" -f 1 |sort -u &
done 

nc -v ${ip} 80 << EOF
HEAD / HTTP/1.0

EOF
```

For anyone who may need it.